# Confusion about HierarchicalRequirement fields

Tags: rally

There are 3 different fields for User Stories for a related parent, and we have run into some confusion about them.

As I understand it:

- The **Parent** field is for a *direct* parent that is another User Story
- The **PortfolioItem** field is for a *direct* parent that is Feature
- The **Feature** field is for a parent (direct or via one or more US parents) that is a
  Feature

If you have the Parent and Feature fields, couldn't you compare the two of them to see if the direct parent is a US or a PI (thus rendering the PortfolioItem field unnecessary)?  It seems to me the one explanation for this is that originally there were only 2 fields, "Parent" and "PortfolioItem", but that restricted the ability to see an associated feature unless you traversed the hierarchy of User Stories up to one with a Feature set as the parent.

So, my questions are:

1. Did I define the three fields and their uses correctly? If so,
2. Why are there 3 when 2 (Parent and Feature) would suffice?
3. Are there other cases I am not considering?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portfolio item field predate the feature field. When we added it to the API we had not yet created the technology to "Roll down" information in our hierarchy. Cases one and two are mainly used to show the direct parent (if any) that is shown in grids and boards.

We will probably keep the portfolioitem field around for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I ran into a situation where I have User Stories who have a parent user story that parents to a feature, but its feature field is not set - is this because it was created before the Feature field was added, or what is going on here?  I thought the feature field was pushed down to lower levels of user stories

Comment: I wonder if you unparent the feature from the story and reparent it if that will cause the roll up to work. Regardless it sounds like a bug. Can I get you to file a support case on that?